# In a Step Function, how do I convert an array of scalars into an array of dictionaries?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

Input of the step - How to Modify the input of the step in a step function from this:

```json
{
    "A": "X",
    "B": "Y",
    "C": [
        "Z1",
        "Z2",
        "Z3"
    ]
}
```

and convert into this

```json
{
    "A": "X",
    "B": "Y",
    "C": [
        {
            "Z": "Z1"
        },
        {
            "Z": "Z2"
        },
        {
            "Z": "Z3"
        }
    ]
}
```

using ASL or C# CDK. I tried to convert an array of strings to an array of elements using:

```json
        "Modify Input": {
            "Type": "Pass",
            "Parameters": {
                "A": "$.A",
                "B": "$.B",
                "C": [
                    {
                        "Z": "States.array($.C)"
                    }
                ]
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append `.$` to the key name if the value is a [JsonPath substitution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-paths.html).  Without it, Step Functions treats the value as a string literal.  Use the `States.ArrayGetItem` [intrinsic function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html#asl-intrsc-func-arrays) to pick items at an index:

```json
{
  "A.$": "$.A",
  "B.$": "$.B",
  "C": [
    { "Z.$": "States.ArrayGetItem($.C,0)" },
    { "Z.$": "States.ArrayGetItem($.C,1)" },
    { "Z.$": "States.ArrayGetItem($.C,2)" }
  ]
}
```

The CDK accepts these literal values. It also provides the optional [JsonPath](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/dotnet/api/Amazon.CDK.AWS.StepFunctions.JsonPath.html) class, which exposes methods for the intrinsic classes and lets you omit the `.$` from key names.  The CDK emits the same State Machine definition output either way.

Comment: what if the array size varies, in this case, we a taking three inputs, what if we get four, two, or one?

Comment: @AhmedHassan If the array length is not known at design-time, you'll need a Lambda task to perform the conversion.

Comment: Can we do this on CDK using C#?
if somehow we get the length or store it into a list of strings.
`List<string> DSIds = new List<string>();`
 `DSIds.Add(JsonPath.Array("$.Z"))`

Comment: @AhmedHassan  Length can be a design-time input variable. In your CDK code, loop from `0` to `length`, doing something like `DSIds.Add({ Z: JsonPath.ArrayGetItem("$.C", i) })` for each item.

Comment: So, to do this we need to find the length, and length can only be found using a lambda or providing the length in the input. 
`{
    "A": "X",
    "B": "Y",
    "C": [
        "Z1",
        "Z2",
        "Z3"
    ],
    "Length": 3
}`

Comment: @AhmedHassan Do you know the array size at _design-time_, when you `cdk synth` the code that defines the Step Function (i.e. length can be different each time you deploy)?  Or is it known only at _run-time_, when you execute the Step Function (i.e. length in the input could be different each time you execute)?

Comment: length can differ at run time. length in the input can be different each time I execute.

Comment: @AhmedHassan Then my first comment applies.